# Can you make a http get request from mongo?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I would like to make some calls to a url from a mapreduce in mongo, but I don't find anyway to do that in javascript except jQuery or lower layers that seem to be accessible only from web browsers

If it may help drive the discussion, I want to call localhost, a c++ server can do complicated things that I can't do in javascript (big libraries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While MapReduce is written in the JavaScript programming language in MongoDB currently, there is not a general set of APIs that allow access to a richer set of platform capabilities.

By design, you cannot access the network (or localhost), files, process, etc. stacks of the host operating system. It's intentionally limited to just the features of MongoDB, and even that is restricted so that the MapReduce will perform optimally.

You will need to write your queries in a different platform and merge the results, or consider other database options.

Comment: ah sh*t that's just too bad. this would allow to bypass the need for hadoop

Answer (score 1):

No. It's a database, not a programming language.

What you can do, however, is to dynamically create your query (from c++ or another language) which would call the server or put the required data dynamically inside.

Comment: What about if I want to do this from mapreduce ?

Comment: You can do lots of things in sprocs, doesn't mean it's a good idea